# How to use a img as a searchbar

Tags: html, css

When I try to make a searchbar we use `<input type="text" placeholder="Search..">`
but that will create a new text box to use. If I try `<input type="image" src="/sources/Search_Icon_v.png" name="saveForm`
it shows as a button.
So what I want here is an image to be used as a textbox/search bar
goal :
[image: Search bar]

Comment: so you want to show an icon or image on the left or right attached to the input field?  Something like that? if not could you please show us an image of the desired output?

Comment: @AhmadDalao sure here is : https://i.imgur.com/EQFG564.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
    #search-input{
      /*use your own image path*/
      background: url(https://img.icons8.com/metro/x/search.png) no-repeat scroll 7px 7px;
      padding-left:30px; /*you may change according to your image width*/
      height:35px /*you may change according to you image height*/
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="search-input"/>
```

Comment: well u see, it is fine as for proportions but when u type on it , its starts from half
https://i.imgur.com/MMwONIw.png

Comment: i guess, your image width is longer, find a smaller image such as 32x32 or try it with this image: https://img.icons8.com/metro/x/search.png

Comment: sir it has nothing to do with search icon, its a different element .

Comment: if you run my code snippet and type on it, will see no problem. just try to do the same as my snippet. if your typings starts from half, either your search icon width is wider or your padding/margin is higher than expected

Comment: also one more thing, how to make the search bar longer?

Comment: set input width longer in css

Answer (score 1):

Hope you meant to having a background image within a txtbox? If so

[image: Search Bar Background Image]

**Answer**

```
<input id="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search..">

<style>

#txtSearch{
background-image: url(https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/binaries/content/gallery/metofficegovuk/hero-images/advice/maps-satellite-images/satellite-image-of-globe.jpg);
}

</style>
```